# Python difflib's ratio, quick_ratio and real_quick_ratio

Tags: python, diff

I've been using [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html#differ-objects)'s `SequenceMatcher`,

And I found the `ratio` function to be too slow.
Reading through the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html#differ-objects), I discovered `quick_ratio` and `real_quick_ratio` that are supposed to be quicker (as the name suggests) and serve as an upper bound.

However, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html#differ-objects) lacks the description on the assumption they make, or on the speedup they offer.

When should I use either version, and what do I sacrifice ?

Comment: The [source code for those methods](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Lib/difflib.py#L647-L686) isn't all that much more helpful.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I somewhat agree. There is decent commentary for `quick_ratio`, and `real_quick_ration` is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I however strongly agree that the docstrings are pretty useless though... `This isn't defined beyond that it is an upper bound on .ratio(), and is faster to compute.`

Comment: Not to be confused with the [Quick ratio](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/q/quickratio.asp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Taking a look

Starting off with the helper method `_calculate_ratio`

```
def _calculate_ratio(matches, length):
    if length:
        return 2.0 * matches / length
    return 1.0
```

#### ratio

`ratio` finds matches, and divides that by the total length of both strings times 2:

```
    return _calculate_ratio(matches, len(self.a) + len(self.b))
```

#### quick_ratio

This is actually what the source commentary says:

```
    # viewing a and b as multisets, set matches to the cardinality
    # of their intersection; this counts the number of matches
    # without regard to order, so is clearly an upper bound
```

and then

```
    return _calculate_ratio(matches, len(self.a) + len(self.b))
```

#### real_quick_ratio

`real_quick_ratio` finds the shortest string, divided by the total length of the strings times 2:

```
    la, lb = len(self.a), len(self.b)
    # can't have more matches than the number of elements in the
    # shorter sequence
    return _calculate_ratio(min(la, lb), la + lb)
```

this is the real upper bound.

### Conclusion

`real_quick_ratio` does nothing to look at the strings to see if there are any matches, it only computes an upper bound based on string length.

Now, I'm not an algorithm guy, but if you think `ratio` is too slow to get the job done, I recommend using `quick_ratio`, since it treats the problem adequately.

#### Note on efficiency

From the docstring

```
    .ratio() is expensive to compute if you haven't already computed
    .get_matching_blocks() or .get_opcodes(), in which case you may
    want to try .quick_ratio() or .real_quick_ratio() first to get an
    upper bound.
```